# PHP MySQl/PDO update millions of data daily

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After researching and trying one month longer, i am going to ask here to get help regarding my large data update issue.

I am trying to update channel data from youtube API regularly in my database. there are more than 15M data in my "channel" Table that need to be updated daily using the Google youtube api. The problem is the update process is really slow.I have tried different way.

Try#1- I am using php curl multi exec to make the process in background. Each time i am calling 500 channel from my database and trying to update these data regularly. its still taking too much time .

Try#2  I thought the slower process is because of longer transaction of mysql query, so i decided to update 500 channel data at once with mysql on duplicate key update query. But the file executed perfectly but the update process take too much time. its not updating 500 at once. And its updating 2/3 at once.

Try#3 I have used the multi curl exec to execute multiple file and those are parallel way for  calling 500 channel each and trying to update in  parallel.Still its not working. its taking too much time more then 10 min to update only 500 channel.

Here i have added my code.

1. Cron curl file. I am using cron job for regular task and using one cron i am trying to call 50 update channel functionalities in parallel . here is my cron-curl.php

   ```
   <?php
   $start = microtime(true);

   $mh = curl_multi_init();
   $handles = array();

   $offset=0;
   for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) {
       $ch = curl_init();

       $rand = rand(5, 50); // just making up data to pass to script

       $url = "http://mydomain/api/cron".$i.".php?id=".$i."&offset=".$offset;
       echo $url;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

       curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
       $handles[] = $ch;
       $offset=$offset+25000;
   }

   // execute requests and poll periodically until all have completed
   $isRunning = null;
   do {
       curl_multi_exec($mh, $isRunning);
       //usleep(20000);
   } while ($isRunning > 0);

   // fetch output of each request
   $outputs = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($handles); $i++) {
       $outputs[$i] = trim(curl_multi_getcontent($handles[$i]));
       curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handles[$i]);
   }

   curl_multi_close($mh);
   $time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
   echo "Process Time: {$time}" . "<br>";
   print_r($outputs);
   printf("Elapsed time: %.2f seconds\n", microtime(true) - $start);
   ?>
   ```

This is the code where the update process is running and the curl is trying to call in background

cron1.php/cron2.php/cron3.php

```
<?php $offset = $_GET['offset'];
$monit_id = $_GET['id'];
$less_id = $offset + 18000;
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
$hostname = "localhost";
$host = "http://v3.domain.com/api/";
$db_name = "****";
$db_user = "****";
$db_password = "****";
$date = strtotime("now");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
define('HOST_NAME', $hostname);
define('BASE_URL', $host);
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST_NAME . ";dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function get_content($url)
{
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM proxy_settings";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $curl = curl_init();


    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $result[0]['ip']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "13012");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);

    if (curl_error($curl)) {

        return 0;
    }
//print_r($html);

    if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200)
        $html = null;
    curl_close($curl);
    $first_step = explode('"ptk":"', $html);
    $second_step = explode('"', $first_step[1]);

    return $second_step[0];
}


if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ . '"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// This code will execute if the user entered a search query in the form
// and submitted the form. Otherwise, the page displays the form above.

/*
* Set $DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
* {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
* Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
*/

$api_key = "SELECT api_key FROM api_settings WHERE type='api'";
$stmt = $db->query($api_key);
$key = $stmt->fetchall();
$api = $key[0]['api_key'];

$DEVELOPER_KEY = $api;

//$DEVELOPER_KEY = '*********************';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$htmlBody = '';
try {

// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
// query term.


    $datet = date('Y-m-d');

    function update_data($total_view, $update_data)
    {

        global $db;

        $query = "INSERT INTO channel (id, views_per_video,total_subs,yt_update,yt_update_no) VALUES " . implode(', ', $update_data) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views_per_video = VALUES(views_per_video),total_subs = VALUES(total_subs),yt_update = VALUES(yt_update),yt_update_no = VALUES(yt_update_no)";

        $sth = $db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute();

    }

    function get_data_from_table($table = NULL, $unumber, $monit_id, $less_id, $offset)
    {
        global $db;
        $datet = date('Y-m-d');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE  yt_update_no < $unumber AND id<$less_id  LIMIT 500 OFFSET $offset";
//print_r($sql.'<br>');
//exit;
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            $newnumbers = $unumber + 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE update_monitor SET number = '$newnumbers' WHERE id = '$monit_id'";

            $pdo = $db->prepare($sql);
            $pdo->execute();
        }

    }

    $d = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM update_monitor where id='$monit_id'");
    $d->execute();


    $unumber_res = $d->fetchAll();
    $unumber = $unumber_res[0]['number'];
    $unumbers = $unumber_res[0]['number'];
    $result = get_data_from_table('channel', $unumber, $monit_id, $less_id, $offset);
//$pieces = array_chunk($result, ceil(count($result) / 50));
//list($array1, $array2,$array3) = array_chunk($result, ceil(count($result) / 3));
    echo "
<pre>";

    $total_view = array();
    $total_subscriber = array();
    $date = array();
    $ids = array();

    $categories = array();
    $view_per_videos = array();
    $update_data = array();
    $last_video_days = array();
    $unumberss = array();
    //print_r($result);exit;
    if ($result) {

        foreach ($result as $searchResult) {


            $id = $searchResult['channel_id'];
            $row_id = $searchResult['id'];
            $id_without_uc = substr($id, 2);
            $channels = $youtube->channels->listChannels("statistics,snippet,contentDetails", array(
                'id' => $id,
            ));

            //echo "<br>";
            if (!empty($channels['items'])) {
                foreach ($channels as $channel) {

                    $total_subscribers = $channel['statistics']['subscriberCount'];
                    $title = $channel['snippet']['title'];
                    $playlist_id = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];
                }


                $videos = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems(
                    'snippet',
                    array('playlistId' => $playlist_id, 'maxResults' => 7)
                );

                // print_r($videos);exit;
                if (!empty($videos['items'])) {

                    if (count($videos['items']) > 0) {
                        $total_result = count($videos['items']);
                    } else {
                        $total_result = 1;
                    }

                    $video_ids = array();
                    $view_counts = 0;
                    foreach ($videos as $video) {

                        $video_ids[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];

                    }

                    $video_info = $youtube->videos->listVideos(
                        'statistics,snippet',
                        array('id' => implode(", ", $video_ids))
                    );
// print_R($video_info);exit;
                    foreach ($video_info as $video) {


                        $view_counts += $video['statistics']['viewCount'];
                    }

                    $view_per_video = $view_counts / $total_result;
                    /*$videw_result = $youtube->search->listSearch('snippet', array(
                                'maxResults' => 1,
                                'channelId' => $id,
                                'order' => 'date',
                            ));
                    //print_r($videw_result);
                                    //exit;
                            foreach ($videw_result['items'] as $result) {
                                $last_upload_Date = $result['snippet']['publishedAt'];
                                $now = time();
                                $past_date = strtotime($last_upload_Date);
                                $datediff = $now - $past_date;

                                $last_video_day = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
                    //print_r($last_video_day);
                                //  exit;
                                // $tags = get_meta_tags("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $result['id']['videoId']);
                                //$url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $result['id']['videoId'];
                                //   $network = get_content($url);
                                //print_r($data);
                                //exit;
                                //  if (isset($network)) {
                                // if ($id_without_uc == $network) {
                                //      $network = "Adsense";
                                //  } else {
                                //   $network = $network;
                                // }
                                // } else {
                                //   $network = '';
                                // }
                            }

                    */
//print_r($tags);
                    //exit;
                    $category = array(
                        "2" => "Autos & Vehicles",
                        "1" => "Film & Animation",
                        "10" => "Music",
                        "15" => "Pets & Animals",
                        "17" => "Sports",
                        "18" => "Short Movies",
                        "19" => "Travel & Events",
                        "20" => "Gaming",
                        "21" => "Videoblogging",
                        "22" => "People & Blogs",
                        "23" => "Comedy",
                        "24" => "Entertainment",
                        "25" => "News & Politics",
                        "26" => "Howto & Style",
                        "27" => "Education",
                        "28" => "Science & Technology",
                        "29" => "Nonprofits & Activism",
                        "30" => "Movies",
                        "31" => "Anime/Animation",
                        "32" => "Action/Adventure",
                        "33" => "Classics",
                        "34" => "Comedy",
                        "35" => "Documentary",
                        "36" => "Drama",
                        "37" => "Family",
                        "38" => "Foreign",
                        "39" => "Horror",
                        "40" => "Sci-Fi/Fantasy",
                        "41" => "Thriller",
                        "42" => "Shorts",
                        "43" => "Shows",
                        "44" => "Trailers",

                    );
                    //  print_r( $categories[$cat_id]);exit;
                    // $categories[$row_id] = $category[$cat_id];
                    // $total_subscriber[$row_id] = $total_subscribers;
                    // $date[] = $datet;
                    // $ids[] = $row_id;

                    // $data[$row_id] = $datet;
                    // $total_view[$id] = $total_views;
                    // $last_video_days[] = 0;
                    //$unumberss[$row_id] = $unumbers;


                    $datet = date('Y-m-d');
                    //$last_30_day_views[$row_id]=$last_30_day_view;
                    // $view_per_videos[$row_id] = array('a'=>$view_per_video,'b'=>$category[$cat_id],'c'=>$total_subscribers,'d'=>$total_views);
                    //   $update_data[$row_id]=array('a'=>$view_per_video,'b'=>$category_name,'c'=>$total_subscribers,'d'=>$total_views,'e'=>$datet,'f'=>$unumbers,'g'=>$last_30_day_view);
                    //$update_data[$row_id]=array('a'=>$view_per_video,'c'=>$total_subscribers,'e'=>$datet,'f'=>$unumbers);
                    $update_data[] = "($row_id,'$view_per_video','$total_subscribers','$datet',$unumbers)";
//print_r($update_data);exit;

                } else {
                    $update_data = $update_data;
                    $sql = "UPDATE channel SET yt_update_no='$unumbers' WHERE channel_id='$id'";

                    $pdo = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $pdo->execute();
                }
            } else {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM `channel` WHERE channel_id='$id'";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                //$result = $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->execute();

            }
        }
        //print_r($update_data);exit;
        update_data($total_view, $update_data);

    }
    $time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
    echo "Process Time: {$time}";
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}

exit;
?>
```

Can you please help how to solve this issue? how to update all 15M channel by one day ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I hope `//$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaSy...-g';` is not your real api key. If so, you should really remove it.

Comment: I have not read all your code, and I don't know the YouTube API, but it sounds to me that what you do is inefficient. Most channels won't have changed in one day, and those that have probably have something little added. Can't you use the YouTube API to detect this?

Comment: You should really debug your code properly and narrow down what, in all that code, it is that takes that long. Are you making a lot of db queries and http requests in loops? (too much code for me to go through now)

Comment: Too late revision history keeps everything :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd first go ahead and measure the time spent on each function/section. However assuming you haven't set up any indexes on your tables (which will radically speed up your queries), I'd go ahead and put an index on columns `(yt_update_no,id)` on table `channel` and on column `(id)` on table `update_monitor`

Comment: And you're doing an **insert** on a function called **update..**

Comment: 1/ Try to avoid to have a foreach where ONE loop = ONE server communication : can't you create ONE query with a list of update then execute it ONCE? Like `UPDATE...; UPDATE...; etc.`; 2/ Can't you check if channel has new data before updating? If you can get the date of last post on channel + you know last time you asked for an update, update only channel that have new content since your last update?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am collecting data from the source in an array and later updating those data at once, in this example the amount is 500 data at once. But this 500 data are not updating at once

Comment: @MickaelLeger Look through the code, you will see that i have tried to do that. I have added all the updated data in an array and later trying to update all at once

Comment: yeah i am using on duplicate key update query @Cemal